# Write specific pages from multiple pdf files to a new pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I have multiple pdf files that I want to extract a group of specific pages from where each set of pages is different for each pdf file. I have created a dictionary with the keys as the pdf file name and the values as the list of pages to be extracted from each pdf file (shown as key). I intend to extract the given pages from the associated pdf file and write them all to one new pdf file so that I can do data extraction on this final file. I have tried PyPDF4 as well as FPDF but no joy as yet as it gives me either a large pdf with blank pages or a pdf with just 1 or 2 pages extracted or error that the pdf object cannot be found. I am hoping to get some guidance on where I am going wrong with my approach. Below is my code:

```
import PyPDF4
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

for pdf,pgs in dic_11_1.items():
  pdf=list(dic_11_1.keys())
  pgs=list(dic_11_1.values())
  for i in range(0,len(pdf)):
    pages = pgs[i]
    object = open(pdf[i],'rb') 
    pdfinput=PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(object,'rb')
    if pdfinput.isEncrypted:
        pdfinput.decrypt('')
    else:
        pdfinput
    for p in pages:
        page=pdfinput.getPage(p)
        pdf_writer=PyPDF4.PdfFileWriter()
        pdf_writer.addPage(page)
        with open('F111.pdf',mode='wb') as output:
            pdf_writer.write(output)
```

The error that I get is 'PdfReadError: Could not find object.'

When I try FPDF with the following code, it runs a long time and gives me a large empty pdf file:

```
from fpdf import FPDF 
import os
for pdf,pgs in dic_11_1.items():
  pdf_in=open(pdf,'rb')
  inputpdf=PdfFileReader(pdf_in,'rb')
  if inputpdf.isEncrypted:
    inputpdf.decrypt('')
  else:
    inputpdf
  for p in pgs:
    content=inputpdf.getPage(p).extractText()
    pdf = FPDF('P','mm','A4') 
    pdf.add_page() 
    pdf.set_font("arial", size = 10) 
    for text in content: 
        text2=text.encode('latin-1', 'replace').decode('latin-1')
        pdf.write(10,text2) 
        pdf.ln(8)
        pdf.close()
        return_byte_string=pdf.output('F_11_1.pdf','S').encode('latin-1')
    pdf_file=open('F_11_1.pdf','wb')
    pdf_file.write(return_byte_string)
    pdf_file.close()
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

The solution provided by @SUTerliakov was great but only wrote the last page or last document from the the dictionary values list of pages. It was resolved with a minor indentation in the code and that got all my data for me. Thanks again @SUTerliakov for starting me on the correct path! Here is your adjusted code:

```
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
open_files = []

try:
   for filename, pgs in dic_11_1.items():
      src = open(filename, 'rb')
      open_files.append(src)
 
      pdfinput = PdfFileReader(src, 'rb')

      if pdfinput.isEncrypted:
        pdfinput.decrypt('')
        print(f'Extracting relevant pages from {filename} to central repository') 
        for p in pgs:
           print(f'{filename} pg{str(p)}')
           pdf_writer.addPage(pdfinput.getPage(p))
        print(f'Writing {len(pgs)} pages to central file')
   Stream=open('F_11_1.pdf','wb')    
   pdf_writer.write(Stream)
finally:
   print('Closing Source File...')
   for f in open_files:
      f.close()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the problem is you're not iterating properly. See comments in code for better understanding.

UPD. `PyPDF4` seems to add only page references to `PdfFileWriter` until it's actually written to some file. So we can close input sources only at the end. Thus this method won't work for large files count (on linux it will be restricted by `ulimit` and by default it's 1024, so we can open only 1000 input files + 1 output file + 3 system streams - stdin, stdout, stderr; this limit can be enlarged with `ulimit -n <count>`).

```py
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter


sect_11_1 = [
    ('filename1.pdf', 0, 1),
    ('filename2.pdf', 0, 1),
]
# note pages are zero-numbered

dic_11_1 = {}

# if sect_11_1 is of another format 
# [('filename', [0, 1]), ...]
# remove star below
for filename, *pages in sect_11_1:
    dic_11_1.setdefault(filename, [])
    dic_11_1[filename].extend(pages)

# if filenames are not repeated, you can do just
# dic_11_1 = dict(sect_11_1)

# you need single writer for all files, don't declare it in a loop
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
open_files = []

try:
    for filename, pages in dic_11_1.items():
        # now you have filename and pages set to 'filename1.pdf' and [1, 3, 4]
        # on second iteration they'll be set to 'filename2.pdf' and [0, 2, 3]
        # ...

        # don't use `object` as variable name: it's valid, but bad style
        # (it shadows builtin `object`)
        
        src = open(filename, 'rb')
        open_files.append(src)
     
        pdfinput = PdfFileReader(src, 'rb')

        if pdfinput.isEncrypted:
            pdfinput.decrypt('')
            # you don't need empty `else`

        for p in pages:
            # you might want to use `p - 1` instead if your input was 1-numbered
            page = pdfinput.getPage(p)
            pdf_writer.addPage(page)

    # when all pages are added, write to output
    with open('F111.pdf',mode='wb') as output:
        pdf_writer.write(output)
finally:  # if something was wrong, do it anyway
    for f in open_files:
        f.close()  # we shouldn't keep files open after program run
```

Comment: it seems a lot more efficient but I am getting 'ValueError: seek of closed file' for line 28 'page=pdfinput.getPage(p)'  .  I tried to add PyPDF4 before PdfFileReader and still get the same error. Each file was opened within the loop so I am not sure if each has to be closed before moving to the next pdf file

Comment: @Sivan sorry, I though for some reason that reader should read whole file into memory, but it's implemented efficient. Should work now (file is open only within context manager, so before it was trying to read on closed file).

Comment: my apologies but it seems I still get the error 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file: ' referring to first file from dictionary.

Comment: the source of the error seems to originate from this trace: '# a dictionary value is a stream.  streams must be indirect'. The dictionary was created as follows:        
 'dic_11_1 = {}
for sub_tuple in Sect_11_1:
    if sub_tuple[0] in dic_11_1:
        dic_11_1[sub_tuple[0]] = [*dic_11_1[sub_tuple[0]],*sub_tuple[1:]]
    else:
        dic_11_1[sub_tuple[0]] = sub_tuple[1:]'

Comment: @Sivan please try again. It should work now (checked locally)

Comment: where Sect_11_1 is a list of tuples (pdffilename,[list of related pages])

Comment: Code you added in comment contradict to format `(filename, [list of pages])`. Are you sure it isn't like `('filename.pdf', 1, 2, 3)` (note brackets absence)?

Comment: I see the problem. the dictionary output format is {'file1.pdf':[1,2,3,4,5],'file2.pdf':[12,17,19]}.  I added to..  for p in pages:   for i in range(0,len(str(p))): page=pdfinput.getPage(i)..... and get back to same error 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file:

Comment: Happiness! It worked. The issue was with the dictionary format as you indicated.

Comment: I have managed to resolved a small error in the code due to incorrect indentation and it works fine now.